# Saving user's height and weight

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How should I store a user's height and weight in a MySQL database such that I can use the information to find users within a certain height or weight? Also, I will need to be able to display this information in either English or metric system.

My idea is to store the information for height in centimeters and weight in kilograms (I prefer metric over English). I can even let the user enter their information and English system, but do the conversion to metric before saving. I think converting kilograms to pounds might be easy to do in SQL, but I'm not sure how easy it would be to convert `178` centimeters to `5'10"` (rounded slightly down).

Should I be saving English and metric values in the database so that I don't need to do conversions when I do my queries? Sounds like a bad idea to store derived/computed values.

Comment: What is your technology beyond mysql. How are your presenting this info to your users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways... one is to just have two numeric columns, one for height, one for weight, then do the conversions (if necessary) at display time.  Another is to create a "height" table and a "weight" table, each with a primary key that is linked from another table.  Then you can store both English and metric values in these tables (along with any other meta info you want):

```
CREATE TABLE height (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    english     VARCHAR,
    inches      INT,
    cm          INT,
    hands       INT  // As in, the height of a horse
);

INSERT INTO height VALUES
    (1,'4 feet',           48, 122, 12),
    (2,'4 feet, 1 inch',   49, 124, 12),
    (3,'4 feet, 2 inches', 50, 127, 12),
    (3,'4 feet, 3 inches', 51, 130, 12),
    ....
```

You get the idea...

Then your users table will reference the **height** and **weight** tables--and possibly many other dimension tables--astrological sign, marital status, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uid         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    height      INT REFERENCES height(id),
    weight      INT references weight(id),
    sign        INT references sign(id),
    ...
);
```

Then to do a search for users between 4 and 5 feet:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN height ON users.height = height.id
WHERE height.inches >= 48 AND height.inches <= 60;
```

Several advantages to this method:

- You don't have to duplicate the "effort" (as if it were any real work) to do the conversion on display--just select the format you wish to display!
- It makes populating drop-down boxes in an HTML select super easy--just `SELECT english FROM height ORDER BY inches`, for instance.
- It makes your logic for various dimensions--including non-numerical ones (like astrological signs) obviously similar--you don't have special case code all over the place for each data type.
- It scales really well
- It makes it easy to add new representations of your data (for instance, to add the 'hands' column to the height table)

Comment: Flimzy, if I understand your solution correctly, I would have `user.height_id` (FK)? If so, wouldn't this make it a bit more complicate for me to query ranges?

Comment: I just updated my answer with how to query... let me know if I need to explain any more.

Comment: I already recommended this book to one other reader today, but [Data Warehousing Toolkit](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309928491&sr=8-1) is the book I've read on this form of "dimension tables", and I would recommend you read it if you're working on any sort of sizeable project. There are likely better books on the topic, but this is the one I'm familiar with, and it did the trick for me.

Comment: Flimzy - I'm trying to digest your solution. What do you think of just storing centimeters and doing the conversions on the fly?

Comment: There is nothing _wrong_ with that method. It will probably work very well for what you're doing--especially if your application is fairly small, and you know you won't expand its core functionality (specifically how it relates to height and weight, etc) very much.

Comment: Say you were dealing with a maximum of 1,000 users? Which approach would you use? What if you had 500,000 users?

Comment: **I** would use the approach I described above. But that doesn't mean the other approach is wrong.  My approach really starts to shine for other, more complex data--like dates. Indexing a DATETIME column, and doing a search on a DATETIME column are both _far_ more expensive than Indexing and searching against an INT column that references a date table.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it the way that you have said you would like to do it, but on the converting part, you would not convert 178 centimeters to 5'10", you would convert it to 70", then if need be, convert that into 5'10".

Comment: jworrin - `178` cms can be easily converted to `70.08` inches, but users would probably prefer to see `5'10"`. If the SQL returns `70.08` inches and I have to apply additional processing on top of the results, I'm concerned that could potentially get slow. What do you think?

Comment: I don't really think the extra processing would be all that great.  Also take into account how often your users are going to want to see their info in the English system.  Either way, I think it is inappropriate to store it in both the English and Metric systems.

Comment: Wait, you are saying that your users are presented with the raw output from your SQL query? What are you using???

Comment: jamie - I'm using LAMP. User search may be something like: find all users that are between 5'5" and 5'10". I want to display height/weight in the format the user prefers.

Answer (score 1):

Think of 5'10" as either 70" or 5.8333333'. In that case, converting betwen 70" or 5.83333 is just a multiplication, so its easy to store in the db as centimeters if you so choose.

The issue of what the user sees is a presentation issue and nothing to do with the database.

Comment: jamie - creating a script to convert `70"` to `5'10"` is trivial. However, if I have to iterate to a large number of query results to make this conversion, I am concerned of a performance hit.

Comment: You would only do the conversion when presenting to the user, you'd do it in the UI layer, and any conversion time will be minuscule compared to all the other stuff going on. If you wanted to search the db for all heights between 5'10 and 6'2, you would convert the two query inputs into cm first, (i.e. two conversions) and then run that query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that storing computed values in this case is not ok. Your choices are perfect.

However, I would do the computations at the application level and query the DB with those values - depending on the language your application is written in , I am sure there are plenty o libraries/modules that are made that can compute those transformations.

Edit - to address the issue of storing computed values in DB:

While this is considered to be a bad practice in working with DBs, I usually am not 100% against this practice - just 90%.

I tend to store computed values in DB only when the computations are complex and would take enormous resources to get to the result wanted - this is clearly **not** the case.

If you would store computed values here you would have only the disadvantages of this technique - when modifying a record, you would have to modify the data in multiple places to keep the consistency of your DB

Comment: Why is storing computed values "not okay"?

Comment: Flimzy, I feel that storing computed values could be seen as redundant data. Don't you think?

Comment: Redundant data is one of the best ways to optimize for performance in a database. I do it all the time. It may violate certain characteristics of normalized form, but when normalized form, or any other "standard" gets in the way of getting the job done, then it's outlived it's purpose.

Comment: That's not to say that storing these values as INTs and converting at display time is _wrong_... just that it's FAR from the _only_ valid approach.

Comment: Flimzy, I assume that you modded Tudor down. I request that you don't mod people down just because you disagree. I personally disagree vehemently with your answer below, but I give you the courtesy of acknowledging that you may have experience which I do not. The suggestions for when to mod down are here: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down