# how to store height in correct format in mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have to insert height in a height column of MySQL database table. by server side coding. but when I tried to enter data in 5'7" format. the ' syntax change the whole query which return an error or no value stored .Is there any solution for it or I go for another format for storing height.

Comment: Just convert the height before storing it to a readily accepted format like 5.70 if you need to display it as 5'7" you can always decode it back  Just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks for answering , Is there any other method of conversion . should i tried foot inch to centimeter

Comment: I recommend saving the height in just inches and formatting outside database - it makes sorting much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some difficult . But you can do this . Please see this discussion and fallow that

[DB: saving user's height and weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591613/db-saving-users-height-and-weight)

Answer (score 1):

if your height col is varchar then

I think you are not using parameters, use it and error will not come.

or replace (') with ('') single ' with double ''

string height = 5'7"

string q = "insert in to height values("+height.Replace("'","''")+")";
but try not using the second option.